# Match partially or completely type parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

I want to check if the type parameter pack are matching partially or completely with another parameter pack.

So far, I'm trying this:

```
template<typename... Arguments>
struct VariadicArguments
{
    template<typename... AnotherArguments>
    struct IsSame: std::bool_constant<sizeof...(AnotherArguments)==0> {};
};

template<typename Arg, typename... Arguments>
struct VariadicArguments<Arg, Arguments...>
{
    template<typename... Args>
    struct IsSame: std::false_type{};

    template<typename AnotherArg, typename... AnotherArguments>
    struct IsSame<AnotherArg, AnotherArguments...>:
        std::bool_constant<
            std::is_same<Arg, AnotherArg>::value &&
            VariadicArguments<Arguments...>::IsSame<AnotherArguments...>::value> { };

    template<>
    struct IsSame<> : std::true_type{};
};

template<>
struct VariadicArguments<>
{
    template<typename... Args>
    struct IsSame : std::false_type {};

    template<>
    struct IsSame<> : std::true_type {};
};
```

I predicted that

```
VariadicArguments<int, float, double>::IsSame<int, float>::value // true because (int, float, double) partially matches (int, float)
VariadicArguments<int, float, double>::IsSame<int, double>::value // false because (int, float, double) doesn't partially matches (int, double) it should be in serial
VariadicArguments<int, float, double>::IsSame<int, float, double>::value // true because they are all same in serial
VariadicArguments<int, float, double>::IsSame<>::value // true because no arguments matches every parameter pack.
```

But I'm getting some compile-time errors

> 1>signal.hpp(25): error C2210:
>   '_Val': pack expansions cannot be used as arguments to non-packed
>   parameters in alias templates
>
> 1>signal.hpp(25): note: see
>   reference to class template instantiation
>   'VariadicArguments::IsSame'
>   being compiled 1>d:\dell\source\repos\mimg\mimg-base\signal.hpp(29):
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation
>   'VariadicArguments' being compiled
>
> 1>signal.hpp(25): error C3770:
>   'unknown-type': is not a valid base class
>
> 1>signal.hpp(25): warning C4346:
>   'VariadicArguments::IsSame': dependent name is not a
>   type 1>d:\dell\source\repos\mimg\mimg-base\signal.hpp(25): note:
>   prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
>
> 1>signal.hpp(25): error C2143:
>   syntax error: missing ',' before '::'
>
> 1>signal.hpp(25): error C2039:
>   'value': is not a member of '`global namespace''
>
> 1>signal.hpp(25): error C2143:
>   syntax error: missing ',' before '>'
>
> 1>signal.hpp(41): error C3769:
>   'VariadicArguments': a nested class cannot have the same name as the
>   immediately enclosing class
>
> 1>signal.hpp(57): error C2953:
>   'VariadicArguments<>::VariadicArguments': class
>   template has already been defined
>
> 1>signal.hpp(16): note: see
>   declaration of
>   'VariadicArguments<>::VariadicArguments'
>
> 1>signal.hpp(67): error C3412:
>   'VariadicArguments<>': cannot specialize template in current scope

Comment: What does "matching partially or completely with" mean? Can you provide a more precise definition?

Comment: I mean that the type of the first parameter pack is same to the another parameter pack. i.e, (type1, type2, type3) matches the another parameter pack (type4, type5, type6) if `is_same<type1, type4>::value` and `is_same<type2, type5>::value` and `is_same<type3, type6>::value`

Comment: But that's... clearly not what you mean. Do you mean the second pack is a prefix of the first parameter pack?

Comment: I mean they matches each type in parameter packs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a simpler `VariadicArguments` (renamed `VarArgs` to make it shorter)

```
template <typename...>
struct VarArgs;

template <typename A0, typename ... As>
struct VarArgs<A0, As...>
 {
   template <typename ... Bs>
   struct IsSame  : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Bs)==0>
    { };

   template <typename ... Bs>
   struct IsSame<A0, Bs...> : VarArgs<As...>::template IsSame<Bs...>
    { };
 };

template <>
struct VarArgs<>
 {
   template <typename ... Bs>
   struct IsSame : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Bs)==0>
    { };
 };
```

Now you can write

```
int main ()
 {
   using ifd = VarArgs<int, float, double>;

   static_assert(  true == ifd::IsSame<int, float>::value, "1!" );
   static_assert( false == ifd::IsSame<int, double>::value, "2!" );
   static_assert(  true == ifd::IsSame<int, float, double>::value, "3!" );
   static_assert(  true == ifd::IsSame<>::value, "4!" );
 }
```

Observe that using `std::integral_constant<bool, BoolValue>` instead of `std::bool_constant<BoolValue>`, this solution works also for C++11 and C++14, not only for C++17.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain this line `struct IsSame<A0, Bs...> : VarArgs<As...>::template IsSame<Bs...>` why there is need `template` here for accessing the member `IsSame`

Comment: @Mohit - well... I've never understood completely when, exactly, the `template` keyword is necessary or not; the problem (as far I know) is that there are circumstances when, parsing the code, the compiler doesn't know if a name refer to a template method (so the following `<` is the start for an explicit template parameter list) or not (so the following `<` can be a relational (less-than) operator). So, in your case, that `template` is to inform the compiler that `IsSame` is a template method.